# Скрыть текст, если не помещается CSS

Tags: css

HTML:

```
 <div class="item">
    <span class="name">E-mail</span>
    <span class="description">ukrka@mail.ru</span>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
span {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Если в блоке `.description` текст превышает допустимую длину - нужно скрыть

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/text-overflow ?

Comment: Да - но не помогло

Comment: `inline-block` все, как всегда, испортил?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мб так подойдёт http://jsfiddle.net/3V57k/2/  проблема в строчности элемента, делаем его блочным, задаём ширину т.к. нужно знать за какую ширину нельзя выходить и флоатим или вместо span использовать div

Answer (score 2):

наверное, автору нужно это http://htmlbook.ru/css/overflow

```
.description {
    overflow: hidden; /* or auto */
}
```

Comment: Toje net :)

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, тогда стоило бы объяснить что вы называете допустимой длиной и показать больше кода, который у вас есть.

Answer (score 1):

Полный бред, в строчном эелементе вполне можно обходится без флота, и фиксированную ширину тоже задавать не надо.

```
span {
  display:inline-block;
  max-width:60px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/w4p57/